# Non-struct objects layout

Tags: c++

I've been reading Lippman's "Inside the C++ Object Model" I encountered the following thing:

> The data members within a single access section are guaranteed within C++ to be laid out in the order of their declaration. The layout of data contained in multiple access sections, however, is left undefined.

Does it mean the comment in the code below is correct?

```
class Foo
{
public:
     Foo(): a_(1), b_(2), c_(3)
     {
          // it does not matter that the order of a_, b_, c_ is the same in class definition and in initialization list, we do not know which one will be initialized first?
     }

public:
     int a_;

private:
     int b_;

protected:
     int c_;
};
```

If it's true, so what about several private sections containing groups of members?

```
class Foo
{
public:
     Foo(): a_(1), b_(2)
     {
          // is initialization order guaranteed?
     }

private:
     int a_;

private:
     int b_;
};
```

In addition, maybe I can read anything about it in the standard?

**UPD**

When I have:

```
class Foo
{
public:
     Foo(): a_(1), b_(2) {}
private:
     int a_;
     int b_;
};
```

I'm sure everything is OK: a_ is initialized before b_ is initialized.

When I have:

```
class Foo
{
public:
     Foo(): a_(1), b_(2) {}
public:
     int a_;
private:
     int b_;
};
```

As I understand, I cannot be sure that a_ is initialized before b_ is initialized.

Why? Because, as we know, the order of initialization is strongly determined by the order of declaration only. But in the quoute above is said, that the order of declaration of a_ (as public) and b_ (as private) is unspecified.

Comment: AFAIK is private, public, protected only the access modifier, meaning the compiler checks when you access that variable and if you are allowed to do so. the data still exists as if it was all public, or whatever. you can even override private methods.

Comment: Initialization order is tied to declaration order, not to layout order.

Comment: Are you talking about standard layout ? If yes, then it is a standard layout if all the members of the struct/class falls under the same access specifier, which is true in your case.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking but in the current standard, members initialized in your initialization list are initialized in the order which they're declared, I.E `Foo(): a_(1), b_(2){}  int b_; int a_;` `b` will be initialized first.

Comment: the way I understand, order of declaration within a given access section is maintained, but accross access sections isnt maintained. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/289568/can-c-access-sections-be-interleaved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Layout:

As said in the text you quoted, the layout depends on both the order of declaration and the access control. All members with the same access control are allocated such that later declared members have a higher within the object. Order of members with different access control is unspecified. Note that this allows for all members to be laid out according to declaration order.

> Nonstatic data members of a (non-union) class with the same access
>   control (Clause 11) are allocated so that later members have higher
>   addresses within a class object. The order of allocation of non-static
>   data members with different access control is unspecified (Clause 11).
>
> [N4296](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf) §9.2/13

.

### Initialization

Initialisation occurs in order of member delcaration, the order of the member initialisers (what's after the `:` of the constructor) does not matter:

> Then, non-static data members are initialized in the order they were
>   declared in the class definition (again regardless of the order of the
>   mem-initializers).
>
> [N4296](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf) §12.6.2/13.3

Access control does not matter.

### Empirical verification

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

struct A
{
    A()
    {
        cout << "A" << endl;
    }
};

struct B
{
    B()
    {
        cout << "B" << endl;
    }
};

struct X
{
    A a;
    B b;
    X() : b(), a() {}
};

int main() {
    X x;
    cout << "a @ " << &(x.a) << endl;
    cout << "b @ " << &(x.b) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

will output ([live on ideone](http://ideone.com/Y5ibG1))

```
A
B
some_address
some_address + 1
```

---

### Addressing your edit:

```
class Foo
{
public:
     Foo(): a_(1), b_(2) {}
public:
     int a_;
private:
     int b_;
};
```

> As I understand, I cannot be sure that a_ is initialized before b_ is initialized.

Yes, you can be sure that `a_` is initialized before `b_`. This is guaranteed by the standard.

> But in the quoute above is said, that the order of declaration of a_ (as public) and b_ (as private) is unspecified.

The quote says that the (relative) layout in memory of `a_` and `b_` is unspecified. This has nothing to do with the order of initialization.

Comment: I was pretty sure that the order of declaration and the order of members in object layout is always the same! It occurs that even if a_ will have higher address than b_, it **can** and **will** be initialized before b_ if I have declared it before b_ in my class definition not depending on the sections they belongs to.